# ctrl + , gets me to settings.json instead of the ui in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[I want to go to here when I use `ctrl + ,`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBI4F.png)

Even when I use the `gear symbol -> settings` or `file -> preferences-> settings` it gets me to the `settings.json` file instead of the UI.

I want to change so that whenever I try to open the settings without the command pallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbench > Settings: Editor`  set to `UI`

`UI` is the default, it must have gotten set to `json` somehow.

Or, same result, delete this line from your `json` file:

`"workbench.settings.editor": "json",`

When you are in the `json` file you can click the little open file icon on the right (next to the split editor icon) to get to the UI.